# Formula in linear algebra for centre of mass

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra book, the following formula: 
$$\vec{OM} = \frac{1}{3} * (\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC})$$
is presented as the **"center of mass"** formula, in connection with the following picture: 
[image]
where O is an arbitrary point and M divides the median, $\vec{AA_1}$, in the ratio 2:1.

**My question**, What has this formula got to do with the centre of mass (is M the centre of mass of the triangle? If so, why?) and what do I use it for?

Comment: Assuming the triangle has a uniform mass distribution, that point is where the center of mass would be.  In more mathematical language, that point is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the triangle.

Comment: All three medians meet at the point. Each median divides the triangle into two triangles having same area (same mass). So each median is the center line of mass. As more than one center line of mass meet at the point, the point is a center of mass.

Comment: Also if the masses are concentrated at the vertices, as opposed to being uniformly distributed, the center of mass is still at _M_. This is called then the barycenter.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $O$ as the origin of your coordinate system.

The center of mass of any set of points $\{\vec{OP_i}\}$ is the point $\vec{OM}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\vec{OP_i}-\vec{OM})=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\vec{OP_i}-\vec{OM})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{OP_i}-n\vec{OM}$ so

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{OP_i}-n\vec{OM}=0\implies\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{OP_i}=n\vec{OM}\implies \vec{OM}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{OP_i}$

Applying this formula to the three vertices of the triangle gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the point $M$ divides the median $AA_1$ in a ratio $2:1$ hence the point $M$ is the centroid of the triangle i.e. the center of mass of triangle where all the mass of triangle can be assumed to be concentrated for uniform mass density.

Formula $\vec{OM}=\frac{1}{3}(\vec {OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC})$ is used for finding out the center of mass i.e. the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of a triangle for uniform mass density.